# PHP replace incorrectly formatted code

Tags: php, validation, str-replace

I'm still learning php and have run up against what should be a relatively easy problem to fix but I'm stuck so any help appreciated :)

I have a Wordpress site which is using a plugin that I don't want to disable.
I'm trying to get all code on the index page validated at w3c and have managed to do so, all apart from one line.

The plugin in is using some javascript to inject some code that is failing validation:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='flags/tpw_flags_css-css'  href='http://www.xxx.xxx/wp-content/plugins/transposh-translation-filter-for-wordpress/widgets/flags/tpw_flags_css.css?ver=0.8.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

The validation error occurs with "id='flags/tpw_flags_css-css'" as it contains a back-slash.
I think in all honesty the id can be removed completely.
I've tried removing from the javascript with no success, so thought I might be able to do with a $html string replace but no joy there either.

I've tried putting various options both in header.php and footer.php before the html content starts and at the end after html closes but no joy:

```
<?php $html = str_replace("id='flags/tpw_flags_css-css'", "", $html); ?>
```

I've heard of preg_replace but still novice with PHP.

Any ideas to the correct solution for this much appreciated
Regards Tony

Comment: Is a 100% valid site really that important and compelling? if it's only for that ID, I wouldn't bother that much...

Comment: I am not familiar with Wordpress... but is the plugin installed in a local directory? Do you have edit access to the plugin code? If so, why don't you just edit the plugin code directly?  Just remember to re-edit it whenever you apply plugin updates.  Can't you bring the issue under the attention of the plugin authors on the Wordpress site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this before anything is output in your header.php file:

```
ob_start('fix_id');
```

Put this in your functions.php file:

```
function fix_id($input) {
    $input = str_replace("id='flags/tpw_flags_css-css'", "", $input);
    return $input;
}
```

Comment: So simple!  Also, maybe using ob_get_contents() even simpler: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php.  ob_start(); $html = ob_get_contents(); $html = str_replace(...);

Comment: Yep - there are a could sibling functions that could be used too - like you suggested. This was the quickest way I saw to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$newStr = preg_replace("/id=\'flags\/tpw_flags_css-css\'/", "", $str);
```

Comment: Thanks Sudhir, trouble is I can't actually identify the string from within this wp plugin that is inserting the html, hence was trying with $html but to no avail.I dont know much about it but would this PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

How about using jQuery to clear the id attribute?  Something like this maybe:

$("link[id='flags/tpw_flags_css-css']").attr('id', '');

EDIT:

If you don't know anything about jQuery, just put this in the page head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("link[id='flags/tpw_flags_css-css']").attr('id', '');
    });
</script>
```

NOTE: Actually, come to think of it, your page will still not validate with this method, because the source will be the HTML which is used before jQuery is applied.

Here is a 100% reliable way: Go to the w3c validation service's 'Validate by Direct Input' tab: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input. Cut and past your page source into the text box. Remove the id attribute from the link tag. Press 'Check' to validate...

UPDATE: Your only options as I see it, are the following:

1. Catch the page output in a string before it is rendered, and filter it using str_replace or preg_replace as suggested by Sudhir - as you already tried unsuccessfully to do.
2. Get hold of the plugin developers and beg them to change the code.
3. Edit the local plugin code directly yourself.